# How do I pass Google Analytics Custom variables in Wordpress ?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress

How do I pass Google Analytics ( Ad-Sense UA ) custom variables in wordpress for diff types of articles. I want to track according to diff categories of content.

Is there any built in plugin to do so ? Or any other approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the category of your post/article: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category
2. Using PHP's `if else` or `switch case`, dynamically build your GA code with Google's custom dimensions. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828
3. Use wp enqueue script to hook it into header, footer, etc. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

At the end of the day, you learn WP's API and remove the dependency on an authoritative plugin.